# Using RDM630 RFID module to write data tags with arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

How can I use RDM630 RFID in arduino to write data tags. I was able to use RDM630 RFID to read data tags using this library https://github.com/electronicdrops/RFIDRdm630 but I couldn't found any code samples about how to write data tags.

I tried to use Software Serial to write data but it doesn't work maybe I am not sending the data well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDM630 reads EM4100 transponders. EM4100 is read only.

That's why you cannot find any samples how to write data.